# Dropzone js not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, dropzone.js

Our application is supposed to extract data from Excel and send it to api in JSON format and API return data which we are showing in koGrid.

Normally its working but when we set `forcefallback = true` and click on uplaod button browser is asking to save *json* data.

Any idea, how to fix it?

Comment: Is this a browser issue? Make sure the content type is text/json and the call that expects the json response should be ajax.